# AspectJ doesnt work fine in Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I tried to create a simple program in java.

In the program I have:

1) Person class - with annotated methods

2) Aspect Class.

Now what I'm trying to do is before the person name is setted, to print some data to a log file and to the console.

So this is what I did:

**Person Class**

```
package pack.bl;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import pack.aop.LogLevel;
import pack.aop.TestAnnotation;

@Component
public class Person {

private String name,dest;
public Person(String name,String dest)
{
    this.setName(name);
    this.setDest(dest);
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

@TestAnnotation(value=LogLevel.INFO)
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    System.out.println("Im " + this.toString() + " My name was changed to " + name);
}

public String getDest() {
    return dest;
}

@TestAnnotation(value=LogLevel.INFO)
public void setDest(String dest) {
    this.dest = dest;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return this.name + "\n";
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person p = new Person("Person1","Kripton");
    p.setName("Person2");
}
```

}

**Aspect Class**

```
package pack.aop;

import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.Signature;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;


@Aspect
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
        "applicationContext.xml"})

public class BeforeAdvice {

private Log logger = LogFactory.getLog("Logger");

@Before("@annotation(testAnnotation)")
public void myBeforeLogger(JoinPoint joinPoint,TestAnnotation testAnnotation)
{
    System.out.println("Okay - we're in the before handler...");
    System.out.println("The test annotation value is: " + testAnnotation.value());
    Signature signature = joinPoint.getSignature();
    String methodName = signature.getName();
    String stuff = signature.toString();
    String arguments = Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs());
    logger.info("Write something in the log... We are just about to call method: "
    + methodName + " with arguments " + arguments + "\nand the full toString: "
    + stuff);
}
```

}

**ApplicationContext.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"    
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

<context:component-scan base-package="pack.bl.Person"/>
```

****NOTE:*** The **LogLevel** is an enum. so it need to work like that, when I'm running 
the program and set the person name, first it's need to go to the 'BeforeAdvice' (because the setName, is annotated with **@testAnnotation**) method in the Aspect class, and execute this method.. after that it's need to comeback to the setName method and set the person name.*

and one more thing, the testAnnotation is an Annotation that I created

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't mentioned anything about how you weave in your question. From what I can see, it looks like you delegate the job to the Spring container. But then you're using Spring AOP and not AspectJ. Although you can use AspectJ annotations also with Spring AOP.

My suggestion is that you divide it into two cases. First ensure that the AspectJ aspect is weaved and use a simpe advice method that only use `System.out.println(..)`, then ensure that the Spring configuration integrates with your aspect and Log enum.

**Wevaing with the AJDT Eclipse plugin**

To enable AspectJ weaving, the easiest alternative is to use the [AspectJ plugin](http://eclipse.org/ajdt/) and use compile-time weaving. After you have right-clicked on your project and enabled AspectJ nature, you will see orange arrows in your code where the advices are weaved in. See picture below for an example.

I'm not sure if your pointcut works. If your advice isn't weaved in any places, you should try this pointcut instead:

```
@Pointcut("execution(@pack.aop.TestAnnotation * *(..)) ")
public void logMethod() {}
```

And advice it like this:

```
@Before("logMethod()")
public void beforeLogMethod(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    System.out.println("Logging..");
}
```

**Integrate aspect and enum with Spring container**

Second,since the aspect is created before the Spring container, you have to retrieve the aspect from the Aspect's factory method `Aspects.aspectOf(pack.aop.BeforeAdvice.class)` or use a factory-method in the Spring configuration.

From the Spring XML configuration, you can retrieve the aspect (object) like this:

```
<bean id="beforeAdvice" class="apack.aop.BeforeAdvice"
    factory-method="aspectOf" />
```

You must also use a factory-method to retrieve the logger that is created outside the Spring container.

I have written a relevant [blog post](http://blog.espenberntsen.net/2010/03/18/aspectj-examples-with-pointcuts-based-on-annotations/) that explains with an example most of your problems and a picture of how elegant the AJDT Eclipse plugin works.

[image]

The image shows two arrows that illustrates an after advice and the last arrow illustrates an around advice.

Comment: thanks for your response, my program is based on those tutrial 
examples http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-springs-aspectj-support and
http://thoughtforge.net/665/creating-a-logging-aspect-with-spring-aop-and-aspectj/
so i don't understand why it's not working fine

Comment: The tutorial uses Spring AOP. The weaving process happens at runtime. It only uses some AspectJ classes but not AspectJ weaving that happens at either load-time or compile-time.

Comment: So, if the weaving process happens at runtime it should reached the BeforeAdvice Aspect, no?

Comment: Its just an example for what i'm trying to do. I have a java application with some custom objects (they are threads), each object has his own log file. so when an event is occur i need to log it in the specific log file. because of that i used those tutrial examples

Comment: It should if you have done it correct. It's no limitation in Spring AOP vs AspectJ weaving when it comes to the before advice on public methods.

Comment: Regarding your title, I will recommend this example: http://eclipse.org/ajdt/demos/HelloWorldAspectJ.html. The AJDT plugin is really good and helps you learn aspect oriented programming. After it works, you can change from AspectJ weaving to Spring AOP with removing AspectJ nature and add a some lines to the Spring config.

Comment: thanks for the link Espen! so what is the difference between AOP and aspectj? just the annotations? i don't understand why what i did,doesn't work, i also use the Retention and Target annotations
before my custom annotation (testAnnotation) so why it doesn't work?

Comment: and one more question, i saw the example in the link that you gave me,
my question is how can i pass object? i mean the after advice in the example will get an object and print his data (just for example)

Comment: it's ok. i know now how to pass parameters

Comment: AspectJ is an AOP technology. It weaves at load-time or compile-time. Spring AOP is done at runtime with proxy objects or inheritance with CGLIB. Both proxy objects and CGLIB objects are managed by the Spring container while AspectJ objects are created before the Spring container is started. AspectJ weaving is more powerful and more difficult than runtime Spring AOP. I recommend the simplest working option in the first round. The AspectJ annotations support in Spring AOP enables you to reuse the annotations with several different weaving technologies.

Comment: Hi Espen thanks for your respone! I already used the AspectJ, for me it's more easy to use.